# How to solve this equation $(x-1)(x+2) + 4(x-1)\sqrt{\dfrac{x+2}{x-1}} = 12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(x-1)(x+2) + 4(x-1)\sqrt{\dfrac{x+2}{x-1}} = 12$

$Domain: x\in (-\infty;-2]\cup(1;+\infty)$

$x = 2\longrightarrow$ Done

How to prove $x = \dfrac{-1-3\sqrt{17}}{2}$ is the last solution? With raise both side by power of two?

Any better way such as factoring, grouping,...?

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Note that $$(x-1)\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x-1}} = \sqrt{(x-1)(x+2)}$$ when $x>1$ and
   $$\begin{align}(x-1)\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x-1}} &= -(1-x)\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x-1}} \\[1mm]&= -\sqrt{(1-x)^2\frac{x+2}{x-1}}\\[1mm]&=-\sqrt{(x-1)(x+2)}\end{align}$$ when $x \le -2$.
2. Substitute $$t = \sqrt{(x-1)(x+2)}$$ Then, how will the equation look like?

Comment: When $x \in (-\infty;-2]$ then $(x-1)\sqrt{\dfrac{x+2}{x-1}}\ne \sqrt{(x-1)(x+2)}$ ?

Comment: You assumed $x>1$.

Comment: @NeatMath I will hopefully fix it :)

Comment: @PhướcVinh Yes, you were right, sorry. I hope it is ok after the edit.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x\neq 1$ you can rewrite your equation as

$$(x-1)(x+2) + 4\sqrt{(x-1)(x+2)} = 12$$

Then call $z = \sqrt{(x+1)(x-2)}$ and solve the quadratic associated equation, and then you pullback to $x$.

Comment: Then $x= 2$ and $x = -3$ are the solutions
It will be confused a bit

Comment: @PhướcVinh Not confusing. Solve the $z$ equation and you get $z_1 = -6$ and $z_2 = 2$. Then pullback solving
$$x^2 + x - 2 = -6$$ which has no solution and
$$x^2 + x - 2 = 2$$ which has solution
$$x_{1, 2} = \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{17}}{2}$$

Comment: Oh dear, $z_2=2\to \sqrt{(x-1)(x+2)} = 2\\\to x^2 + x - 2 = 4$

Comment: @PhướcVinh Ops, my bad! You're right!